# Google Analytics Event Not Working on Submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics

I would like to send event when someone submits form on my website, but it's not working.

This is my form script:

```
$('.wicmsLeadSubmit').prop( 'disabled', false );

$('.wicmsLeadSubmit').click(function(){
    var leadForm = $(this).closest('form');     
    var leadImie = $('.lead_imie', leadForm);
    var leadTelefon = $('.lead_telefon', leadForm);
    var leadEmail = $('.lead_email', leadForm);

    if(leadImie.length){   
       if(leadImie.val()==''){
           leadImie.attr('placeholder', 'Podaj imię');
           return false;
       }
    }   


    if(leadEmail.length){         
       if(leadEmail.val() == ''){    
           leadEmail.attr('placeholder', 'Podaj email');
           return false;
       }                        
       var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
       if(reg.test(leadEmail.val()) == false) {  
           leadEmail.val('');
           leadEmail.attr('placeholder', 'Podałeś błędny email');
           return false;
       }
    }
    ga('send', 'event', 'Submit', 'Modal Rejestracja', $('.reveal-modal.formularz').id());                      
    ga('set', 'userId', leadEmail.val() ); 

    $.ajax({
       type: 'POST',
       url: '/lead',
       dataType: 'json',
       data: {
           lead_email: leadEmail.val(),
           lead_imie: leadImie.val(),
           lead_source: $(':hidden.lead_source', leadForm).val(),
           lead_telefon: leadTelefon.val()
       },
       success: function(data){   
           if(data.error.exists==true){
                     $('.powiadomienie', leadForm).hide();
                     $('.blad', leadForm).show();
                     $('.blad', leadForm).append(' Tresc błedu: '+data.error.message);
                     $('.wicmsLeadSubmit', leadForm).prop( 'disabled', true );

           }
           else{

               $('.wicmsLeadSubmit', leadForm).prop( 'disabled', true );
               $('.powiadomienie', leadForm).show();
           }
       },
   });

   return false;
});
```

And this is what makes error:    ga('send', 'event', 'Submit', 'Modal Rejestracja', $('.reveal-modal.formularz').id());

And when I try to look for errors there is only one: 
$(...).id is not a function

Please help.

Comment: It seems that $('.reveal-modal.formularz') does not return any elements. So empty array.id() is not a function

Comment: `.id()` isn't a jquery method

Comment: It should return id of this div:<div style="opacity: 1; visibility: visible; top: 1042px; display: block;" id="wtorek" class="reveal-modal formularz open" data-reveal="" ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.id()` is not a jQuery function, if you want the `id` attribute, do this:

```
ga('send', 'event', 'Submit', 'Modal Rejestracja', $('.reveal-modal.formularz').attr('id'));
```

Comment: Thanks, this is it.